# Relation between $\frac{1}{K} \sum_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and $ \frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are non-negative values, then can we say about any inequality between the two terms given below

$\frac{1}{k} \sum_i^k \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ and $ \frac{\sum a_i}{\sum b_i}$

It is also given that $a_i \leq b_i$ $\; \forall i$.  If so, is there exist a simple proof to show the relation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation.

$$\frac12\left(\frac14+\frac25\right)<\frac{1+2}{4+5}$$
but
$$\frac12\left(\frac24+\frac15\right)>\frac{2+1}{4+5}.$$

---

**Alternatively:**

$$\frac12\left(\frac23+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda}\right)=\frac56$$

while

$$\frac{2+\lambda}{3+\lambda}=1-\frac1{3+\lambda}$$ takes any value in $(\frac46,\frac66)$.